# How to find out what Git version the PhpStorm Built in is using?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Because of [CVE-2017-1000117](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqh8xf482j.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/T/#u) I have to upgrade git on my system. For the executable, I just downloaded the latest client from git-scm. Using the native git client from PhpStorm does not work for me so I am bound to using the built in.

But how do I find out what version of Git PHPStorm is using? 
Is that version safe to use for `git clone --recursive`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm uses Git executable that has been set in File | Settings | Version Control | Git and no other. There is no built in Git client in PhpStorm.

Comment: Ah, I see now. _Built in_ and _Native_ refer to the ssh executable, not to the git executable. Thank you

Comment: That's correct. Check the descriptions of each mode here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-git-integration.html#d398922e736